# Show one video in webview by link from YouTube

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to show a video from YouTube in my app in webview but  I want to show it without other **videos** and I don't want to use YouTube APl just by take the **link** of video

Comment: Have you taken a look to the Youtube API iFrame? It looks like you can specify a single video to play. 
Here is the documentation link:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library works well for me check it : [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player)

Add it's dependency in gradle file

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:9.0.1'
}
```

In order to start using the player you need to add a YouTubePlayerView to your layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Get a reference to the YouTubePlayerView in your code and initialize it

```
YouTubePlayerView youtubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
getLifecycle().addObserver(youtubePlayerView);

youtubePlayerView.initialize(new YouTubePlayerInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitSuccess(@NonNull final YouTubePlayer initializedYouTubePlayer) {
        initializedYouTubePlayer.addListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady() {
                String videoId = "6JYIGclVQdw";
                initializedYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}, true);
```

That's all you need, a YouTube video is now playing in your app.